# Go - When can the "&MyStruct{1, 2}" syntax to instantiate a struct and get a pointer to it be useful?

Tags: go, struct

I have been following the tour of the Go programming language to get familiar with the language, and one feature of the language left me wondering.

In the step about [Struct Literals](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/5), they explain that you can instantiate a structure by multiple ways:

```
type Vertex struct {
    X, Y int
}

var (
    v1 = Vertex{1, 2}  // has type Vertex
    v2 = Vertex{X: 1}  // Y:0 is implicit
    v3 = Vertex{}      // X:0 and Y:0
    p  = &Vertex{1, 2} // has type *Vertex
)
```

I have no problem understanding how the three first ways are working and when they can be useful, but I cannot figure out any use-case for the last solution `p = &Vertex{1, 2}`.

Indeed, I cannot think of any case where one would have to instantiate a `*Vertex` without having already a variable of type `Vertex` available and used in your code:

```
func modifyingVertexes(myVertex *Vertex) {
    myVertex.X = 42;
}

func main() {
    myVertex := Vertex{1, 2}

    modifyingVertexes(&myVertex)

    fmt.Println(myVertex.X)
}
```

I could see a use if the following was possible:

```
func modifyingVertexes(myVertex *Vertex) {
    myVertex.X = 42;
}

func main() {
    modifyingVertexes(&Vertex{1, 2})

    fmt.Println(???.X) // Accessing the vertex initialized in the modifyingVertexes func call
}
```

But since I don't think it's possible, I really have no idea on how it could be used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very common Go idiom, returning the address of an initialized `struct` variable.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y int
}

func NewVertex(x, y int) *Vertex {
    return &Vertex{X: x, Y: y}
}

func main() {
    v := NewVertex(1, 2)
    fmt.Println(*v)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/UGOk7TbjC2a

Output:

```
{1 2}
```

---

It's also a very common idiom for hiding unexported (private) `struct` fields.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Vertex struct {
    x, y int
}

func NewVertex(x, y int) *Vertex {
    return &Vertex{x: x, y: y}
}

func (v *Vertex) Clone() *Vertex {
    return &Vertex{x: v.x, y: v.y}
}

func main() {
    v := NewVertex(1, 2)
    fmt.Println(*v)

    w := v.Clone()
    fmt.Println(*w)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ScIqOIaYGPn

Output:

```
{1 2}
{1 2}
```

---

In Go, all arguments are passed by value. Using a pointer for large `structs` is more efficient. A pointer is also necessary if you wish to change the value of a `struct` argument.

Comment: This type of use was indeed suggested by a friend of mine and something that I thought about, but I don't see why you couldn't return just a `Vertex` instead of a `Vertex*` here. I guess the example I gave is a bit too simple to understand the full extant of the use-case you're talking about maybe?

Comment: @AntoineB One reason, say the struct is much larger than just two fields and you need to pass it around a lot, then it's much better to pass a pointer to it because if you pass a value it gets copied every time. When you pass a pointer only the pointer gets copied, which is like 4B or whatever as opposed to the whole struct which could a lot bigger than that.

Comment: @AntoineB Another reason if the type implements an interface in terms of some methods that mutate the state of the receiver's value, you'll need to implement the methods on a pointer, and then a non pointer value cannot be used in place where the interface is expected, you need to pass a pointer value of that type instead.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the clarifications, I can definitely see the use now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think about the two styles of initialization (e.g., `foo{}` and `&foo{}`) is through what you hope to accomplish. If you need a value object which will never change, then `foo{}` does just fine. On the other hand, if you will need to later change an object, then a reference is best. For example:

```
// using a value object because it will never change
oneHundredDollars := Cash{Amount: 100, Currency: "Dollars"}

// using a reference because the account's balance will change.
a := &Account{Balance: 0}

// changes Balance
a.Deposit(oneHundredDollars)
```